# округление javascript

Tags: javascript

Складываю два десятичных числа и получаю: ***0.30000000000000004***

```
console.log(0.1 + 0.2);
```

Я понимаю что так устроен js. Это его внутреннее представление чисел с плавающей точкой, на которое выделяется сколько то бит. Мой вопрос в следующем, какие надёжные техники , формальные и не формальные позволяют избежать подобных проблем.

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл ответ:

Всё дело в том, что в стандарте IEEE 754 на число выделяется ровно 8 байт(=64 бита), не больше и не меньше.

Число 0.1 (одна десятая) записывается просто в десятичном формате. Но в двоичной системе счисления это бесконечная дробь, так как единица на десять в двоичной системе так просто не делится. Также бесконечной дробью является 0.2 (=2/10).

Двоичное значение бесконечных дробей хранится только до определенного знака, поэтому возникает неточность. Её даже можно увидеть:

```
alert( 0.1.toFixed(20) ); // 0.10000000000000000555
```

Когда мы складываем 0.1 и 0.2, то две неточности складываются, получаем незначительную, но всё же ошибку в вычислениях.

Есть два способа сложить 0.1 и 0.2:

1. Сделать их целыми, сложить, а потом поделить:

`alert( (0.1 * 10 + 0.2 * 10) / 10 ); // 0.3`

2. Сложить, а затем округлить до разумного знака после запятой. Округления до 10-го знака обычно бывает достаточно, чтобы отсечь ошибку вычислений:

`var result = 0.1 + 0.2;
alert( +result.toFixed(10) ); // 0.3`

Answer (score 1):

```
parseFloat(0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Только ещё нужно кастовать к числу, поскольку toFixed() возвращает строку.

Comment: @АлексейУколов - согласен.